# stuck on TTY after ctrl + alt + f12 ubuntu 22

Tags: nvidia, tty

Ubuntu had weird behaviour  after I accidentally hit Ctrl + ALt + f12. I ended up in TTY shell.
After some reading, I hit Ctrl + Alt + F2 to go back on the principal UI.
It worked paritally for my first monitor but the second one stayed black.

Even after rebooting I obtained the same behavior.
After checking my nvidia Drivers I saw that my installed drivers where from X.org instead of Nvidia.

in setting --> software updates --> settings --> Additional Drivers -->
check your graphic card driver installed is the proprietary one: Nvidia driver metapackage from ...

after this, I rebooted and my second screen started working again.

Just sharing

Comment: Please don't answer in your question, thanks.